where we should send request to third party api at nuxt 3 application
I have nuxt 3 application and independent express app,
i have endpoints and i need to use them in my nuxt app i used like below structure

import axios from 'axios';
const serviceInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
  headers: { 'x-api-key': import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
});
export const updateComponentStatus = async (componentName, status, theme) => {
  try {
    const response = await serviceInstance.patch('/components/status', {
      name: componentName,
      theme_name: theme,
      status: status,
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating component status:', error);
    throw error;
  }

};

this is working but for use env variables i need to use VITE prefix this is how look my .env this is not feeling right , i don't want seperate request i want manage all them in same file maybe it could be in store but this time the store file is too messy any advice ?
VITE_API_KEY=
VITE_API_URL=
BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000

